# Can I set command output to basepython in tox.ini?

Tags: python, tox

Can I set command output to basepython in tox.ini? I want to do something like this:

```
[tox]
envlist =
    pymain
    pynext

[testenv:pymain]
basepython=$(get_python_main_path)

[testenv:pynext]
basepython=$(get_python_next_path)
```

get_python_main_path and get_python_next_path are shell commands.

Comment: nope... you could do something like `python build_tox.py && tox ...`